# Display button when UICollectionView Cell Tapped

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm having an Image and when user taps twice on that image then I show a button which has a tick sign as if like user has ticked that Image. I have set the button hidden at first from Storyboard.

I'm getting cell tap using this

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
if collectionView == self.subOptionsCollectionView{
        let imageNamed = "\(customizeOptionSelected[indexPath.row])"

        shirtImage.image = UIImage(named: imageNamed)

        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(doubleTapped))
        tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
        collectionView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }
}
func doubleTapped() {
    print("Double Tap")
}
```

But how do I display that tick/button ?

Comment: why are you setting the tapgesture in did select method you must set it in cell for row at indexpath method

Comment: you have to reload collection view  to show recent changes in cell.

Comment: dont reload just use the selected row and make changes to the particular cell

Comment: first of all why are you writing the tapgesture in didselect method

Comment: On double tap just enable and unhide the button.

Comment: Had implemented Tap gesture in CellForRow now. Still try to figure out the way to display that button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

put your code in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` instead of `didSelect` and disable the `userInteraction` of collectionView then you can set the isHidden property of the button to true in `doubleTapped`, but you have to change the function like this(Swift3):

```
func doubleTapped(selectedIndex: IndexPath) {
    print("Double Tap")
}
```

and change the selector like this:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: self.doubleTapped(selectedIndex: indexPath))
```

### **There is another solution:**

put your code in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` instead of `didSelect` then you can set the isHidden property of the button to true in `doubleTapped`, but you have to change the function like this(Swift2):

```
func doubleTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
     let buttonPosition: CGPoint = sender.convertPoint(CGPointZero, toView: self.collectionView)
     let indexPath: NSIndexPath = self.collectionView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(buttonPosition)!
     //you have the selected cell index
     let cell = self.collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)
     //now you have the cell and have access to the button

}
```

and add the gesture like this:

```
let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.doubleTapped(_:)))
cell.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
```

Comment: How do I call cell's button over here ?

Comment: @UmairAfzal How ? I tried setting delegate but instead of displaying tick/button on that particular cell, it is showing on other random cells too on scroll.

Comment: there is no need to use delegate, you can find the index by extracting the point from sender which is UITapGesture.

Comment: @Mina the button is inside the CELL.

Comment: How would you go about detecting the button tap in a cell without delegate ?

Comment: @Nitesh you can easily get the cell, i've updated my answer.

Comment: @UmairAfzal there is no need of delegate in such a case, please don't confuse Nitesh

Comment: @Nitesh selector is for swift 2 not swift 3.
swift3 syntax is exist in part one of my response.

Comment: Yes that is showing incorrect. `UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: self.doubleTapped(selectedIndex: indexPath))`

Comment: the first doubleTapped function structure is different from the second one, the first one receive indexPath as input parameter, but the second one has sender which is UITapGesture. so the selector for these functions must be different as you can see in the code. and be careful about the swift version, i've noted the versions in code.

Comment: You need to place some kind of boolean on your model so that the other cells wouldn't be showing on other random cells on scroll.

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4 Update :**

```
  @IBAction func doubleTap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

        let buttonPosition: CGPoint = sender.location(in: self.collectionView)
        guard let indexPath = self.collectionView?.indexPathForItem(at: buttonPosition) else { return }

        print ("doubleTap on cell at: ", indexPath)

        let cell = self.collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
        // now you have the cell and have access to the button
    }
```